# What is the t-score for the relationship between X & Y

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, linear-regression

The police chief is concerned about alarm systems degrading in city buildings and failing to operate. Using a sample of 100 alarms in operation the previous year, the police department regresses whether an alarm failed (Y coded 1 for failure and 0 for no failure) on the age of the alarm system. The department gets the following regression equation (X is age in years):

```
Y= .05 + .015X        standard error of the slope=.0005
```

What is the t-score for the relationship between X & Y?

This is a problem in my book I can't find an answer.  I would love an explanation of the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The $t$-score for a parameter $\beta_i$ is defined as $t_i = \frac{\hat{\beta_i}}{s_{\hat\beta_i}}$, in your case you should find the $t$-score of the slpoe

$t=\frac{0.15}{0.0005}$